# Port Forwarding Double NAT

Tags: nat, forwarding, wan

Over the past few days , I am trying, without success, to do port forwarding in order to connect my Camera from remote (WAN) and not just from home (LAN).

This is the IP of the camera : 192.168.1.110 , and this is the forwarding table:

```
Local                                     External
IP Address    Start Port    End Port    IP Address  Start Port  End Port    Protocol    
192.168.1.110   34567        34567       0.0.0.0    34567       34567         BOTH
```

This is the output of tracert command in windows (first 2 lines) :

```
 #tracert yahoo.com 
    Tracing route to yahoo.com [206.190.36.45]
    over a maximum of 30 hops:

1  1ms  9ms  1ms  192.168.1.1
2  9ms  9ms  12ms 10.161.32.1
```

Both are private IP's , so I suspect my compuer is behind 2 routers and this is why I am failing to do port forwarding. this assumption makes sence ? if so , what can I do to resolve this?

Default Gateway IP brings me to the router's GUI and ,there I can see the local IP address (192.168.1.1) and WAN address (starts with 77.42 .... which is not private). Any suggestions?

Comment: There's two possibilities here... your ISP could be employing [CGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), in which case you don't *have* a dedicated public IP and there's nothing you can do, or that internal address could be one end of a PPP tunnel (as is common on e.g. ADSL connections) and you do have a public address on the other end (and your config should be working as-is...). See if you can find out if your ISP uses CGN.

Comment: I think CGN can be being applied even when your WAN IP is a public IP. That IP could be shared with many other people and none of you are allowed to port forward.  So the IP your ISP assigns you can be public or private with CGN.   So yeah ask your ISP if it's the case.  If your ISP has CGN you could ask them and look up what you can do.. like there are still ways around it apparently ..  https://ipcamtalk.com/threads/carrier-grade-nat-problem-how-to-access-my-ip-cameras-vpn.13437/

Comment: Thank you both for the detailed answer. I will verify with my ISP if this is indeed the case here.